# Using summarise to obtain percentage of selected subgroups

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(Mode = c("air", "water", "rail", "road", "air", "water", "rail", "road", "air", "water", "rail", "road"), Year = c("2000", "2000", "2000", "2000", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2002", "2002", "2002", "2002"), Country = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany" ), VALUE = c(2, 3, NaN, 5, 1, NaN, 12, 19, 29, 30, 31, 32))
```

The objective is to get percentage of specific/selected sub-groups (mode of transport). In this case, I want to get, for a given year and country, what is share/percentage of rail and water and also in another case every other subgroup except for road (i.e.: air+water+rail).

So in this case for Year 2000 in USA, percentage of rail and water is 3+0 / (2+3+5) * 100 = 30% and for non-road subgroup (ignoring NaN) is 2+3 / (2+3+5)*100 = 50%

My starting point is this - ignoring selected grouping, but then I am lost:

```
df %>% 
 na.omit() %>% 
 group_by(Year) %>% 
 mutate(pct = (VALUE/sum(VALUE) * 100))
```

Any one can guide the logic/ or thinking in solving this?

Comment: try `df %>%  group_by(Year) %>% mutate(pct = VALUE/sum(VALUE, na.rm = T))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got the logic. I replaced `NA` by 0 just in order to keep them in the df. Then, group by year and country, as you would imagine. Finally, use `[]` to select only a portion of your vector.

```
require(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(VALUE=replace_na(VALUE,0)) %>% 
  group_by(Year,Country) %>% 
  mutate(rail_water = sum(VALUE[Mode %in% c('rail','water')])/sum(VALUE),
         non_road = sum(VALUE[!Mode %in% c('road')])/sum(VALUE))

# A tibble: 12 x 6
# Groups:   Year, Country [3]
   Mode  Year  Country VALUE rail_water non_road
   <fct> <fct> <fct>   <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 air   2000  USA         2      0.3      0.5  
 2 water 2000  USA         3      0.3      0.5  
 3 rail  2000  USA         0      0.3      0.5  
 4 road  2000  USA         5      0.3      0.5  
 5 air   2001  USA         1      0.375    0.406
 6 water 2001  USA         0      0.375    0.406
 7 rail  2001  USA        12      0.375    0.406
 8 road  2001  USA        19      0.375    0.406
 9 air   2002  Germany    29      0.5      0.738
10 water 2002  Germany    30      0.5      0.738
11 rail  2002  Germany    31      0.5      0.738
12 road  2002  Germany    32      0.5      0.738
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you, I just did not think about using [ ] to select portion of the vector. Thanks so much, again!